# Flex - Vertical Align Cells in a Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble vertical aligning text inside cells in a DataGrid in Flex.  I tried this.setStyle("vertical-align", "middle) in an itemRenderer on the column but it doesn't seem to work... I tried verticalAlign as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like flex doesn't support it natively but I found a hack to do the job.

Make the cells inherit a Box and put a label inside the box.  Then you can set verticalAlign="middle" on the Box.

Answer (score 2):

```
try use <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle">:


<s:GridColumn headerText="Action" >
 <s:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
     <s:GridItemRenderer>
       <s:layout>
      <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" paddingLeft="5"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Button label="View"  click="outerDocument.view(event)" />
    <s:Button label="Unlink" click="outerDocument.unlink(event)"  />
  </s:GridItemRenderer> 
  </fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>    
</s:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

The mx:Text and TextField controls do not directly support a verticalAlign style.

The easiest would be to align the contents of their container e.g. `container.setStyle("verticalAlign", "bottom")` or so.

If the container uses absolute layout, you could set one of *top*, *bottom*, *left*, *right* styles to `0`, to align accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataGrid verticalAlign property (set to "middle")

verticalAlign: The vertical alignment of a renderer in a row

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/2/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#styleSummary

Answer (score 0):

Try textAlign on the DataGridColumn.